# android-studio debugging works, just not with this app. why?

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

I'm using android-studio 0.8.4 with my phone connected over USB.

One app is **working** fine with debugging no trouble with android-studio. 
In the other **not-working** app it's waiting for debugger handshake message on the phone when this message goes away - just a black screen for appox. 30sec then the debug connection is lost (timeout) and the app is running normally just without debugging.

My first thought is that my gradle.build script is different between those apps. the **working** app uses just jars while the **not-working** app is using repo urls (which is new to me, not sure how to call it) like

```
compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao:1.3.7'
compile 'com.google.inject:guice:4.0-beta:no_aop'
compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
```

Could this be the reason for the debugger not to work?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing roboguice from the project debugging worked again normally. I've tried all robo/guice libs from v2 to v4-beta4 ...